# Running sum / totals column in query with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

how can i have a running balance in my query with sqlalchemy?

i have:

```
table1                         table2
item_id  journal_id  qty       journal_id  journal_date
2           25       654          25         31/05/2013
5           45       123          45         25/04/2013
2           65       887          65         03/04/2013
2           85       321          85         13/02/2013
5           85       225
```

i need a query that will give me the following results:

```
 item_id   journal_date  qty  balance
 2          13/02/2013   321   321   
 2          03/04/2013   887   1208
 2          31/05/2013   654   1862
 5          13/02/2013   225   225
 5          25/04/2013   123   348
```

Comment: Is this for double-entry accounting? Handling the balance calculation at the client site should be easier; I don't think there is an SQL solution without subqueries or stored procedures.

Comment: its a actually for an avg Inventory report. i have no problem with using subqueries or stored procedures, as long as i could pull a report that gives me accurate results. i would actually be fine with one item_id at a time.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `WITH ROLLUP` SQL clause that does what you need, but it's not built into SQLAlchemy and isn't supported in every DBMS, but assuming you're using something relatively decent you should be good.

There's a [helpful recipe on the SQLAlchemy mailing list](http://osdir.com/ml/sqlalchemy/2012-05/msg00004.html) that points you in the right direction on how to support it in SQLAlchemy.

Of course, you could just create a running subtotal by iterating through your result set when you deal with the data.

Comment: i never heard of that, i am pretty new to this so no wonder. however i am going to research that. i am using sqlite.